# MVC dropdownlist don't select item with value pass from ng-model - hope get reply?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to edit data though angularjs and I've got all the data in view - but the only problem is that the dropdownlist does not select the value that is passed to it and I don't know why.

JS Code:

```
function getCustomer() {
    var promiseGetStudent = SPACRUDService.getCustomer(ShareData.value);

    promiseGetStudent.then(function (pl) {
        pl.data.MirageDate = $filter('date')(pl.data.MirageDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        $scope.Cust = pl.data;
    },
          function (errorPl) {
              $scope.error = 'failure loading Student', errorPl;
          });
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<table class="table">
                <td style="width:200px; text-align:center; vertical-align:central">إسم العميل</td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: -3px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0; vertical-align:central; width:50%;">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon ion ion-person"></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="إسم العميل" ng-model="Cust.CustomerName">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:125px; vertical-align:central" class="text-center">المدينة</td>
                            <td style="padding:0; vertical-align:central">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="Cust.CityID" name="cid" id="cid" />
                                @Html.DropDownList("CityID", null, "إختر المدينة", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width=100%", @ng_model = "Cust.CityID" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I get the value of "CityID" but the dropdownlist does not select it from the items, and when I look into html of the dropdownlist I found:

```
<option value="? number:2 ?"></option>
```

So please what is the problem here and how can I make it work?